# Should I expect search engines (particularly Google) to crawl EPUB and MOBI files?

Tags: google-search, search-engines, googlebot, ebooks

Some of our content we are publishing as EPUB and MOBI ebook format files.

Will search engines crawl and index these in the same way as PDFs currently are?

If the answer is yes, could you point me to some sample results page that shows how they appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those aren't document types that search engines index and return in their search results.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to John's answer, specific to Google: [File types indexable by Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35287?hl=en)

> Google can index the content of most types of pages and files. The
>   most common file types we index include:
>
> - Adobe Flash (.swf)
> - Adobe Portable Document Format (.pdf)
> - Adobe PostScript (.ps)
> - Autodesk Design Web Format (.dwf)
> - Google Earth (.kml, .kmz)
> - GPS eXchange Format (.gpx)
> - Hancom Hanword (.hwp)
> - HTML (.htm, .html, other file extensions)
> - Microsoft Excel (.xls, .xlsx)
> - Microsoft PowerPoint (.ppt, .pptx)
> - Microsoft Word (.doc, .docx)
> - OpenOffice presentation (.odp)
> - OpenOffice spreadsheet (.ods)
> - OpenOffice text (.odt)
> - Rich Text Format (.rtf, .wri)
> - Scalable Vector Graphics (.svg)
> - TeX/LaTeX (.tex)
> - Text (.txt, .text, other file extensions), including source code in common programming languages:
>
>   - Basic source code (.bas)
>   - C/C++ source code (.c, .cc, .cpp, .cxx, .h, .hpp)
>   - C# source code (.cs)
>   - Java source code (.java)
>   - Perl source code (.pl)
>   - Python source code (.py)
> - Wireless Markup Language (.wml, .wap)
> - XML (.xml)